# PayFlowPro: 57 Terminal is not programmed for this service

Tags: paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

In paypalfunctions.asp, I set Env = "pilot" to test some code changes.
Got this error on an authorize "57 Terminal is not programmed for this service".

My live account has been up and running for years. I'm recoding to work with "paypalfunctions.asp" instead of the old .NET .dll.

Do I need to request or enable the Sandbox with Paypal somewhere?

Most of the demos I've seen to get the sandbox talk about registration as a new customer; but I'm an existing customer.

This [Paypal Page](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/kw/sandbox) says:

```
 **API Endpoint**: When testing, you must submit all API requests, including CREATESECURETOKEN calls, to the endpoint https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com.
```

That's the URL that gets used when the variable ENV is set to "PILOT".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and according to [this site](http://www.linkpointcart.com/administration/index.php3?ID=606)

> This error means that your merchant services account does not accept the credit card type that was entered by your customer.

So I believe it could be a matter of trying to submit (for example) an American Express or Discover card while your account is not set up to accept those card types.